# Docker - Python SDK won't read Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, sdk

i'm using the Python Docker SDK and i'm trying to automate image building for some heavy load testing and logging. If you'd like to say: "Why can't you use a shell script instead?" I can't, and that's out of the scope of the question.
This is the structure of my project:

my_package/

Dockerfiles/

simulation.py

simulation.py let's an object instance of my_package.server.server_manager.ServerManager build the images, and, by doing what the SDK's documentation tells me, the core command that builds the image is:

```
    image, build_logs = self.client.images.build(
        path = self.build_context,
        tag = self.image_tag,
        dockerfile = self.dockerfile_path,
        decode = True
    )
```

by passing ../../ as build_context and Dockerfiles/Rest/Dockerfile as dockerfile_path; but, when said command runs from simulation.py, i get the following error:

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2714355989: is a directory
Exit code: 1

I'm very confident that the errors is caused by wrong build and dockerfiles paths, but i can't really wrap my head around it, since the documentation says that dockerfile should be relative to path, and it is as such, yet it doesn't work.

Side note: i'm using wsl2 and docker desktop, but i get the same output using the vanilla docker engine on a clean ubuntu22.04 installation.